# using sed to replace the contents of a file is not working in bash script

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, sed

I have the following `sed -e 's/<em\:update.*//g' install.rdf > install.rdf` in a bash script, and it works on command line, but in the bash script install.rdf ends up a blank file.

When I run `sed -e 's/<em\:update.*//g' install.rdf > install.rdf` command line, then 2 lines are stripped out of the file.

Any idea why `sed -e 's/<em\:update.*//g' install.rdf > install.rdf` is not working in the bash script?

Comment: What UNIX and version of `sed` do you have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i -e 's/<em\:update.*//g' install.rdf
```

When you redirect output to a file in truncate mode, the file is truncated first, before it's read. Thus, the result is an empty file. Using `sed -i` avoids this.

Portable (and hopefully not too insecure) solution:

```
(set -C &&
 sed -e 's/<em\:update.*//g' install.rdf > install.rdf.$$ &&
 mv install.rdf.$$ install.rdf)
```

:-)

Comment: However, `-i` is a GNU extension.

Comment: @Matthew: Thanks! Fixed up the answer with something a little more general (albeit insecure if the directory is writable by malicious parties).

Comment: The shell variable $$ is classically used for non-hostile environments avoiding problems with shared names:  `sed ... install.rdf > install.rdf.$$; mv install.rdf.$$ install.rdf`.

Comment: @Jonathan: I've revised my solution with your suggestion, as well using `set -C` to mitigate symlink attacks or anything. It can fail if the filename is already taken, but at least people can't trick you into clobbering files you don't intend to. ;-)